# is there a way to pass string id in django url?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-urls

**Template.html for all model row**

This Template is a table to show all my model data when the user click one row **tr tag**
its should direct them to the view of the row to edit or update.

**tr onclick="location.href='{% url 'quality_control_point_view' object.id %}'"**

When this object.id was int AutoField it worked just fine for me but when i modify my model so that the primary key is Charfield. an error keep coming

```
            <form action="" method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <table id="material_issued">
                        <tr >
                            <th>{% translate 'Reference' %}</th>
                            <th>{% translate 'Title' %}</th>
                            <th>{% translate 'Product' %}</th>
                            <th>{% translate 'Operation' %}</th>
                            <th>{% translate 'Control Per' %}</th>
                            <th>{% translate 'Type' %}</th>
                            <th>{% translate 'Team' %}</th>
                        </tr>
                {% for object in table %}
                        <tr onclick="location.href='{% url 'quality_control_point_view' object.id %}'">
                            <td>{{ object.id }}</td>
                            <td>{{ object.title }}</td>
                            <td>
                                {% if object.raw_product is not None %}
                                    {{ object.raw_product }}
                                {% elif object.spare_product is not None%}
                                    {{ object.spare_product }}
                                {% else %}
                                    {{ object.bom_product }}
                                {% endif %}
                            </td>
                            <td >{{ object.operation.capitalize }}</td>
                            <td>{{ object.control_per.capitalize }}</td>
                            <td>{{ object.type.capitalize}}</td>
                            <td>{{ object.team }}</td>
                        </tr>
                {% endfor %}
                        <input type="hidden" name="length" id="num" value="{{ table.count }}">
                    </table>
                </form>
```

**Urls.py for specific row**

```
path('Quality/QualityControlPoint/<str:qcp_id>', views.QualityControlPointView.as_view(),
```

**Urls.py for all model row**

```
path('Quality/QualityControlPoint', views.AllQualityControlPointView.as_view(),name='all_quality_control_point'),
```

**View.py for all model row**

```
class AllQualityControlPointView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'all_quality_control_point.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['table'] = QualityControlPoint.objects.all()
        my_filter = QualityControlPointFilter(self.request.GET, queryset=context['table'])
        context['table'] = my_filter.qs
        context['my_filter'] = my_filter
        return context

    def get(self,request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

**View.py for selected row**

```
class QualityControlPointView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'quality_control_point_view.html'
    form_class = QualityControlPointForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        suppliers = {}
        instance = QualityControlPoint.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['qcp_id'])
        form = self.form_class(self.request.POST or None, instance=instance)
        for item in Suppliers.objects.all():
            suppliers[item.pk] = item.name
        raw_materials = serializers.serialize("json", RawMaterials.objects.all())
        spare = serializers.serialize("json", SparePartsStock.objects.all())
        bom = serializers.serialize("json", BillsOfMaterial.objects.all())
        context['raw_materials'] = raw_materials
        context['spare_parts'] = spare
        context['boms'] = bom
        context['suppliers'] = suppliers
        context['form'] = form
        return context

    def get(self,request, *args, **kwargs):

        context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)

    def post(self,request, *args, **kwargs):
        title = request.POST['title']
        operation = request.POST['operation']
        control_per = request.POST['control_per']
        control_frequency = request.POST['control_frequency']
        control_frequency_time = request.POST['control_frequency_time']
        control_frequency_interval = request.POST['control_frequency_interval']
        type_of = request.POST['type']
        norm = check_exist(request, 'norm')
        norm_unit = check_exist(request,'norm_unit')
        tolerance_from = check_exist(request, 'tolerance_from')
        tolerance_to = check_exist(request, 'tolerance_to')
        team = request.POST['team']
        responsible = request.POST['responsible']
        instruction = request.POST['instruction']
        message = check_exist(request, 'message_if_failure')
        note = check_exist(request, 'note')
        product_list = request.POST.getlist('product')
        product_list = list(product_list[0].split(","))
        for item in product_list:
            all_list = item.split('_')
            model = all_list[0]
            product = all_list[2]
            obj = QualityControlPoint.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['qcp_id'])
            obj.title = title
            obj.operation = operation
            obj.control_per = control_per
            obj.control_frequency = control_frequency
            obj.control_frequency_time = control_frequency_time
            obj.control_frequency_interval = control_frequency_interval
            obj.type = type_of
            obj.norm = norm
            obj.norm_unit = norm_unit
            obj.tolerance_from = tolerance_from
            obj.tolerance_to = tolerance_to
            obj.team_id = team
            obj.responsible_id = responsible
            obj.instruction = instruction
            obj.message_if_failure = message
            obj.note = note
            obj.spare_product_id = None
            obj.raw_product_id = None
            obj.bom_product_id = None
            if 'raw' in model:
                obj.raw_product_id = product
            elif 'spare' in model:
                obj.spare_product_id = product
            else:
                obj.bom_product_id = product
            obj.save()
            return redirect('quality_control_point_view', self.kwargs['qcp_id'])
```

**Error**

```
Reverse for 'quality_control_point_view' with arguments '('QCP/0001',)' not found. 2 pattern(s) tried: ['en/Quality/QualityControlPoint/(?P<qcp_id>[^/]+)\\Z', 'Quality/QualityControlPoint/(?P<qcp_id>[^/]+)\\Z']
```

Comment: the error is saying that you tried to pass the string param `"QCP/0001"` but the regex pattern specifically excludes forward slash character `(?P<qcp_id>[^/]+)`

Comment: so how i'm supposed to pass this string while it's containing "/" .

Comment: NVM, i found if i change <str:parameter> to <path:parameter> it worked just fine